# How to validate mongodb backup and restore

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.0, mongodb-3.4

I am using `mongodump` to create a backup of the db based on some query params and `mongorestore` to restore the same in another `mongodb` in a diff environment.

How can I validate whether the dump created fetched all the records and also whether the restore of dump to the target db is done properly?

Comment: Is your source database changing while you are taking the `mongodump`? What level of validation are you looking for? What sort of deployment are you backing up (standalone, replica set, or sharded cluster)? Since you have a query filter an obvious starting point would be to compare counts between your two MongoDB deployments, but if the data is changing you will have to allow for some deviations. If you want a deeper comparison (such as documents having identical fields & values) you would have to write (or find) a tool to iterate and compare documents in your source and target deployments.

Answer (score -1):

You should try this:

https://studio3t.com/

You can use "data synchronization" And if I remember correctly, you can validate data between 2 DB.

You can use it non-commercial use for free. Just download, and at the first start you can select between commercial and non-commercial use.

Also this: https://robomongo.org/

Comment: Thanks for the link . But it looks like paid product . I was looking something on scripting side .  Thanks

Comment: @Abhishekkumar If you have further constraints (such as a script that is  is freely available and runs in a specific environment like the `mongo` shell or your preferred O/S), you should include these details in your question to provide context for those trying to help.